# Im trying to modify a javascript omegle bot that sends 1 message to making it send 2

Tags: bots, innerhtml

When I put the modified code that I made into the omegle developers console,it only outputs the first message, and not the rest.

The original code only sends one message:

```
function executeOmegle()
{
    let btn = document.querySelector('.disconnectbtn')
    let messageBox = document.querySelector('.chatmsg')
    let sendBtn = document.querySelector('.sendbtn')
    btn.click()
    messageBox.innerHTML="Hello, how are you? To know about me visit codermen.com."
    sendBtn.click()
}

setInterval(executeOmegle,4000)

I modified it to where it should be able to send two in the following, however it only outputs the first message:
function executeOmegle()
{
    let btn = document.querySelector('.disconnectbtn')
    let messageBox = document.querySelector('.chatmsg')
    let sendBtn = document.querySelector('.sendbtn')
    btn.click()
    messageBox.innerHTML="Hello, this is the first message"
    sendBtn.click()
    messageBox.innerHTML="Hello, this is the second message - the one that doesnt send."
sendBtn.click()
}

setInterval(executeOmegle,4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second sendBtn.click() should be indented

```
function executeOmegle()
{
    let btn = document.querySelector('.disconnectbtn')
    let messageBox = document.querySelector('.chatmsg')
    let sendBtn = document.querySelector('.sendbtn')
    btn.click()
    messageBox.innerHTML="Hello, this is the first message"
    sendBtn.click()
    messageBox.innerHTML="Hello, this is the second message"
    sendBtn.click()
}

setInterval(executeOmegle,4000)
```